# Update sql to pervious date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in my table in SQL with the next format:

```
2013-09-20 10:12:08
```

I want to update this field to `X` days ago. for example, I want to update this field to 5 days ago, and it will be:

```
2013-09-15 10:12:08
```

There is SQL command for this?

Comment: What datatype is that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET dateColumn = dateColumn - INTERVAL 5 DAY
-- WHERE codition here
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c8e8/1)

In MySQL, you can use [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) but can be express using `INTERVAL` with `+` and `-` operator.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the `interval` literal is ANSI SQL Although the standard (and several DBMS apart from MySQL) require the value `5` to be enclosed in single quotes: `interval '5' day`